# Spring Security with Multi-Tenant Architecture

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I wonder if anyone has worked with Spring Security with a Multi-Tenant architecture.

I'm having a little difficulty performing the implementation and if possible would like to study some examples.

Best Regards

Comment: post your code, then we can help you..

Comment: Hi @user3145373ツ. I have not started the implementation of the security layer of my project. 
But I would like opinions if it is possible to accomplish with Spring Security. Thanks!

Comment: @João Manolo, You need to modify your question to say that there is no implementation..

Answer (score 3):

In a multitenant application the authentication and authorization will need to capture the tenant details. So you need to have a third tenant details along with username and password in the request. You can have a custom implementation of [UserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) that loads the tenant details given a web request. You need to store the `UserDetails` loaded in a your own implementation of [UserDetails](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html). This will take care of authentication.

You will need to do some code to use the tenant token for authorization. Depending on the type of Autorization(Database/JaaS/OAuth/Spring Security based), you need to enhance that module and feed in your tenant details to use tenant.

Comment: he did ask specific spring security question, granted not a detailed one it is sufficient for people to understand the requirement and provide a relevant answer. No need for more threads of same thing.